# Could someone please explain this bash command?

Tags: bash, terminal

From the website for [RVM](https://rvm.io):

```
bash < <( curl https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

What does that first less-than symbol do? What about the `<(`? I know this is a stupid question, but I'd love to understand this.

Comment: This is most definitely _not_ a stupid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash's [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) replaces `<( ... )` and `>( ... )` with pipes from/to children.  Hence the whole thing means "create a pipe from `curl ...`, and use it as stdin to bash".

Rather pointless, it would be better written

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Comment: You say it's pointless, however I've noticed that bash will complain about all kinds of syntax errors and not found commands when using the normal pipe syntax. In other words, `command | bash` seems to behave differently than `bash file-name` or `bash <(command)`.

Comment: For instance, `bash <(cat file-name)` works just like `bash file-name`, while `cat file-name | bash` does not. Admittedly that's a contrived example, however the same happens with `curl` or `wget` too. I'm really new to Linux and bash scripting though so could anyone explain what the reason for this difference is?

Answer (score 2):

It's called process substitution. The ouput of the `curl` command is sent via an anonymous named pipe to the standard input of `bash`. Basically what that whole command is doing is executing what's retrieved by `curl` as a shell script.

I consider it risky, but some people seem to be OK with it. If you retrieve the file and run it in a separate step, though, you have an opportunity to inspect it first. Whatever you do, if you do it together ***don't*** run it as root or under `sudo`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. Using `sudo` with this *does* sound like a recipe for tragedy, so I'll train myself to be on the lookout for that sort of thing!